# Wrong output after compilation

Tags: java

I tried to use bubble sort to sort array, but last index is missing after every iteration.

Below is my Java Code, pls help.

```
package arraytest;

public class BubbleSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] bblSort = {30, 45, 8, 204, 165, 95, 28, 180, 110, 40};

        for(int i=0; i<bblSort.length; i++){
            System.out.print(" " +bblSort[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("        ..........");

        sort(bblSort);
    }

   public static void sort(int [] bblSort){

       int temp=0;
       for(int i=0; i<bblSort.length-1; i++){
           for(int j=0; j<bblSort.length-1 -i; j++){

               if(bblSort[j] > bblSort[j+1]){
                   temp = bblSort[j];
                   bblSort[j] = bblSort[j + 1];
                   bblSort[j+1] = temp;
               }
               System.out.print(" "  +bblSort[j]);
           }
           System.out.println();

       }
   }
}
```

The Output of the program after compilation

```
 30 45 8 204 165 95 28 180 110 40
        ..........
 30 8 45 165 95 28 180 110 40
 8 30 45 95 28 165 110 40
 8 30 45 28 95 110 40
 8 30 28 45 95 40
 8 28 30 45 40
 8 28 30 40
 8 28 30
 8 28
 8
```

Comment: What did you find when you used a debugger?

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: Please review carefully what you are actually printing.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your implementation. Simply output the contents of `bblSort` again after you sorted it and you'll see it looks like this:

```
[8, 28, 30, 40, 45, 95, 110, 165, 180, 204]
```